# subtract and add values from a running baseline in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I have a starting baseline for two metrics. I would then like to add or subtract from these metrics based on grouping two columns.

**df**

```
    id  date    hey hi  total   pwr_sum hey hi  de_pwr  de_total    base    base pos
    aa  q1      1   1   2       20      1   0   5       1           200     40
    aa  q2      2   0   2       4       2   0   6       2           200     40
    bb  q1      0   0   0       0       0   2   12      2           500     10
    bb  q2      1   1   2       40      0   0   0       0           500     10









    The base for aa is  200 and 40
    The base for bb is  500 and 10
    
    The values will either be subtracted or added to each of these numbers based on grouped id 
    and date.


    For instance with aa, q1: we start out with base 200 and base pos 40
    We subtract 'pwr_sum' 20 from 200, giving us a new value of 180 and we add 'de_sum' 5 , 
    giving a final value of 185
    For 'base pos', we subtract the 'total' of 2 from 40, giving us 38, and then add the 5 
    from 'de_total' giving us 39.

    For aa q2, now the new starting base will be 185 and the new starting base pos will be 39

    We are grouping by id and date.
```

**Desired**

```
id  base basepos date   hey hi  total   pwr_sum hey hi  de_total de_pwr new_pwr new_pos
aa  200  40      q1     1   1   2       20      1   0   1        5      185     39
aa  200  40      q2     2   0   2       4       2   0   2        6      187     39
bb  500  10      q1     0   0   0       0       0   2   2        12     512     12
bb  500  10      q2     1   1   2       40      0   0   0        0      472     10
```

**Doing**

```
def f(x):
    d = {'pwr_sum': [x['pwr_sum'].sum()],
         'de_pwr': [x['de_pwr'].sum()],
         'new_pwr': [x['pwr_sum'].sum() - x['de_pwr'].sum()],
         'new_pos': [x['pwr2'].count() - x['de_pwr'].count()]}  # <<< HERE
    return pd.DataFrame(d)



out = df.groupby(['id', 'date', 'basepos']) \
        .apply(f).reset_index().drop(columns='level_3')


out['new_pos'] = out['new_pos'].astype(float) + out.groupby('id')['new_pos'].cumsum()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you can use `cumsum` to calculate the accumulated change and then add them to the first base value, it is equivalent as calculating a new base and do the calculation again on the new base:

Comment: I will try this thank you